# is uncached memory always contiguous?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

I am trying to understand the internals of cached and uncached memory from linux perspective. 
Is an uncached memory always contiguous? How does the linux handle internally between the cached and uncached addresses and which module is responsible for this?

Comment: Which of the myriad caches are you talking about?

Comment: And what problem are you trying to solve, exactly ?

Comment: The relationship between program addresses and physical RAM locations is completely arbitrary. The CPU has mapping that converts from one to the other, and works on page boundaries. Caching doesn't enter into it.

Comment: I meant about the general cache and uncached buffers that linux kernel VMM handles. But I am not clear if the memory allocated from an uncached pool is always contiguous because if I measure the performance of both the pools, I see that uncached pool works better for video than a cached pool.